# Adding standardized RMSE of validation set after last epoch has finished

Tags: pytorch

I am in the middle of modifying my copy of [training.py from *Deep Learning with PyTorch*, by Eli Stevens, Luca Antiga, and Thomas Viehmann](https://github.com/deep-learning-with-pytorch/dlwpt-code/blob/master/p2ch11/training.py).  I want to compute the standardized RMSE of the validation set after the last epoch of training has finished.

I know how to do this, in general.  However what is the best way to do this in the indicated project?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I know how to do this, **in general**"*?

Comment: I know how to compute the standardized RMSE, in general.